# retrieve WHEEL_DELTA from wParam in WM_MOUSEHWHEEL msg in C#

Tags: c#, hook, mouseevent, dllimport

I'm using global hooks from user32.dll with dllimport in C#. Keyboard one works fine, but the mouse wheel events are a problem. This is my mouse event callback:

```
        private IntPtr MouseInputCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(mouseHookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);

            int eventType = wParam.ToInt32();
            if (eventType == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
            {
                int wheelMovement = GetWheelDeltaWParam(eventType);
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(mouseHookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

Everything goes fine until I have to retrieve the WHEEL_DELTA value that shows which way and how much the wheel was scrolled. Since C# lacks the [GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro, I'm using this code that should do the job:

> private static int GetWheelDeltaWParam(int wparam) { return
>   (int)(wparam >> 16); }

But the output is always 0, which doesn't make any sense.

**EDIT - result:**

```
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT mouseData = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
        int wheelMovement = GetWheelDeltaWParam(mouseData.mouseData);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public Point pt;
            public int mouseData;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public long dwExtraInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Something seems amiss. You compare `wParam` for **equality** with the message id, but then want the same value's top 16 bits to vary?

Comment: Something probably is amiss, but in that case what would the correct solution be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM` is for extracting the mouse wheel delta from the `wParam` of a **`WindowProc`**, whereas what you have is a **`LowLevelMouseProc` callback**. In [your case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> wParam [in]
>
> Type: WPARAM
>
> The identifier of the mouse message. This parameter can be one of the following messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_MOUSEMOVE,
>   WM_MOUSEWHEEL, WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, or WM_RBUTTONUP.

the `wParam` is simply `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`; to get the wheel delta, you need to look in

> lParam [in]
>
> Type: LPARAM
>
> A pointer to an [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

and within that struct,

> mouseData
>
> Type: DWORD
>
> If the message is WM_MOUSEWHEEL, the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta. The low-order word is reserved. A positive
>   value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the
>   user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward,
>   toward the user. One wheel click is defined as WHEEL_DELTA, which is
>   120.

you will find your value.

Please don't ask me for the necessary C# P/Invoke details for working this struct as I would almost certainly get them wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are looking for `WM_MOUSE**H**WHEEL`, which is movement horizontally of the wheel *(side to side)*,

**NOT** the scrolling action of the wheel, which is `WM_MOUSEWHEE`L.

```
        if (eventType == WM_MOUSE**H**WHEEL)
        {
            int wheelMovement = GetWheelDeltaWParam(eventType);
        }
```

Are you sure that's what you want?  Maybe just substitute `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` here, as well as other suggestions.